# JWT refresh in flutter

Tags: flutter, jwt

How to implement JWT token refresh with flutter?

> which package i need to use?

> Can that be implemented with the HTTP package?

*What i have tried*

```
getauth(String username, String password) async {
http.post(url, body: {
 'username': "atom",
 'password': "abi",
 'grant_type': "password",
 'client_id': "2LJhXdj2Cu0LlVqHk2ilm1WWHtdwK**********",
 'client_secret':
     "buQIh6tLPC0hG6QZUMm7yP7QuSjBLiffTBx3zY2HYxw95ssXQ4F85ttE5fGHInm1LBkk9GhGiHZCvoR21l4bqIOQTTJBo0nJ5******************"
}).then((response) {
 Map<String, dynamic> responseMap = json.decode(response.body);
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   print(response.body);
 }
 print(response.body);
});
}
```

Comment: You need to use interceptor. Interceptors allow us to intercept incoming or outgoing HTTP requests using the HttpClient . By intercepting the HTTP request, we can modify or change the value of the request.

Comment: does the http plugin can handle interceptor?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [http_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor) and implement expired token retry policy

Exp.

```
class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
  @override
  Future<bool> shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(ResponseData response) async {
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      // Perform your token refresh here.

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Interceptors allow us to intercept incoming or outgoing HTTP requests using the HttpClient . By intercepting the HTTP request, we can modify or change the value of the request